# Infinite staircase to a circle

Tags: geometry, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, circles, coordinate-systems

Suppose you start at $(0,0)$ on the unit disc and repeat the following procedure again and again:

1. Face east and walk half-way to the circumference.
2. Face north and walk half-way to the circumference.

What is your limiting position $(x,y)$?

This is a fun problem thought of by a friend. I'm interested to see if anyone can find a nice, clean solution to it.

Comment: I assume you keep doing steps of the type described.  But do you alternate east, north, east, north,...; or is the pattern of directions east, north, west, south, east, north, west, south,...?

Comment: That's another problem I guess

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. You just alternate between east and north.

Comment: what do you mean by limiting position? because you can't reach the border anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by rush the border... If you draw a picture it's visually apparent that you'll approach some point on the circle. The distances you travel in each step get shorter and shorter.

Comment: but in any case I think you can't reach the border, you just get closer over and over.

Comment: the question is correct as Joshua wants the *limiting* position.

Comment: And the limit does exist. Each sequence is strictly monotonous and is bounded.

Comment: Numerically one obtains ${y_n\over x_n}\to0.79995\ldots$; but the limit point is definitely not $\bigl({5\over\sqrt{41}},{4\over\sqrt{41}}\bigr)$.

Comment: If $x_n$ and $y_n$ is the position after one north east then north move then  

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{2}((1-y_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}-x_n)=  \frac{1}{2}(x_n+(1-y_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})$$ $$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{1}{2}((1-x_{n+1}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}-y_n)=  \frac{1}{2}(y_n+(1-x_{n+1}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})$$
We know the limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$ exist. Letting them be x and y and substituting into the equations as limit values does not let us find them though. We simply get that x and y lie on the circle.

Comment: Infact, that is reasonable as if we start anywhere in the circle the sequence will end up on the boundary in the first quadrant.

Comment: I have a conjecture: if we play the same game on the $p$-norm unit ball we get a limit point $Q_P=(x_p,y_p)$ for each $p$. I claim that all these point lie on the same line. In this case, the limit point for $Q_2$ for $p=2$ could be obtained easily from $Q_1=(2/3,1/3)$ and $Q_\infty=(1,1)$

Comment: The points on the unit disc for which the procedure (starting with an eastward move) produces the same limiting position lie on a continuous curve passing through (0,-1), (0,0) and the limiting position. Points on another curve, passing through (0,-1), ($\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}$) and the limiting position, have the same property if we start with a northward move. Some progress might be made by attempting to describe these curves.

Comment: Correction: the last of those coordinates should be ($\tfrac{1}{2},0$).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all your comments. I think the most concrete progress has been Paul's provision of the recurrence relations. Can anyone see if they might be solvable analytically?

Comment: I really don't think there can be a satisfactory answer except a numerical computation (by the way it ends up at $(0.780886\ldots,0.624673\ldots)$). Now if instead you moved $1/n$-th of the way and let $n$ tend to infinity, it could be a fun ode problem.

Comment: It's interesting that if you add those numbers up it's scary close to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that some more users will have a look at your nice question within the next days. With respect to the many comments, it would be helpful if you could remove the ambiguities in your question. Maybe also adding one or two examples could help improving clarity. Regards,

Comment: The first digits of $x_{\infty}$ are $0.7808861196194307100503584709816329393433\dotsc$ and this does not appear to be an algebraic number. Hope this helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a nice, clean answer I'm afraid - just some observations.

Your staircase looks like this:

[image]

As noted below,

$$x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-y_{n-1}\ ^{2}}-x_{n-1}\right)\\ 
y_{n}=y_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-x_{n}\ ^{2}}-y_{n-1}\right)$$

with first few terms

\begin{align}
x_0&\quad\dfrac{1}{2}\\
y_0&\quad\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\\
x_1&\quad\frac{1}{8} \left(2+\sqrt{13}\right)\\
y_1&\quad\frac{1}{16} \left(\sqrt{47-4 \sqrt{13}}+2 \sqrt{3}\right)\\
x_2&\quad\frac{1}{32} \left(\sqrt{-4 \sqrt{3 \left(47-4 \sqrt{13}\right)}+4 \sqrt{13}+197}+2 \sqrt{13}+4\right)\\
\dots
\end{align}

It gets a bit rediculous after that, so decimal approximation is preferable, as given in the comments.

We start to get a fuller picture though by taking steps of $\dfrac{1}{k}$ instead of $\dfrac{1}{2}$, so our sequence becomes

$$x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\sqrt{1-y_{n-1}\ ^{2}}-x_{n-1}\right)\\ 
y_{n}=y_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\sqrt{1-x_{n}\ ^{2}}-y_{n-1}\right)$$

with first few terms:

\begin{align}
x_0&\quad\dfrac{1}{k}\\
y_0&\quad\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{k^2}}}{k}\\
x_1&\quad\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{k^4}-\dfrac{1}{k^2}+1} k+k-1}{k^2}\\
y_1&\quad\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{k^2}} k-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{k^2}}+\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{k^4}-\dfrac{1}{k^2}+1} k+k-1\right)^2}{k^4}} k}{k^2}\\
\dots
\end{align}

which looks like this:

[image]

where clearly $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\arctan\dfrac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\{x_{n},y_{n}\}=\{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}.$

## Note

Fairly good approximation for point on $k$ steps is

$$\left\{\frac{e^{2/\pi }}{\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{1}{k-\zeta (3)}+1\right)^{k-\zeta (3)}\right)^{4/\pi }+e^{4/\pi }}},\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{k-\zeta (3)}+1\right)^{k-\zeta (3)}\right)^{2/\pi }}{\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{1}{k-\zeta (3)}+1\right)^{k-\zeta (3)}\right)^{4/\pi }+e^{4/\pi }}}\right\}$$

```
Manipulate[range = 100;
 h[{x_, y_}] := {x + 1/k (Sqrt[1 - y^2] - x), 
y + 1/k (Sqrt[1 - (x + 1/k (Sqrt[1 - y^2] - x))^2] - y)};
 x0 = N[0 + 1/k (Sqrt[1 - 0^2] - 0)];
 y0 = N[0 + 1/k (Sqrt[1 - x0^2] - 0)];
 nl = NestList[h, {x0, y0}, range];
 Show[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
Join[{{0, 0}, {1/k, 0}}, 
  Flatten[{{nl[[#, 1]], nl[[#, 2]]}, {nl[[# + 1, 1]], 
       nl[[#, 2]]}} & /@ Range[range], 1]] // Line,
Join[{{0, 0}}, 
  Flatten[{{nl[[#, 1]], nl[[#, 2]]}} & /@ Range[range], 1]] // 
 Line,
Join[{{1/k, 0}}, 
  Flatten[{{nl[[# + 1, 1]], nl[[#, 2]]}} & /@ Range[range], 1]] //
  Line, {{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}} // Line,
Red, PointSize[Large], 
Point[{p1 = {(k - k^3 + 2*Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^4 + 2*k^5 + 
       Sqrt[2]*
        Sqrt[(-1 + 3*k^2 - Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^3 - 
            3*k^4 + 2*k^6)*(-1 + 4*k^2 - 3*k^4 - 
            2*Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^5 + 2*k^6)])/(-1 + 
       5*k^2 - 4*k^4 + 
       4*k^6), (Sqrt[
        1 - k^(-2)]*(1 - 4*k^2 + 3*k^4 + 
         2*Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^5 - 2*k^6 + 
         Sqrt[2]*k*
          Sqrt[(-1 + 3*k^2 - Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^3 - 
              3*k^4 + 2*k^6)*(-1 + 4*k^2 - 3*k^4 - 
              2*Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k^5 + 2*k^6)]))/((-1 + 
         Sqrt[1 + k^(-4) - k^(-2)]*k)*(-1 + 5*k^2 - 4*k^4 + 
         4*k^6))},
  {1/Sqrt[2 - k^(-2)], Sqrt[(-1 + k^2)/(-1 + 2*k^2)]}
  }],
{{1/k, 0}, p1} // Line,
Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[ArcTan[y0/x0]], Sin[ArcTan[y0/x0]]}}],
Blue, PointSize[Large], 
Point[{E^(2/Pi)/
   Sqrt[E^(4/Pi) + ((1 + (k - Zeta[3])^(-1))^(k - Zeta[3]))^(4/
        Pi)], ((1 + (k - Zeta[3])^(-1))^(k - Zeta[3]))^(2/Pi)/
   Sqrt[E^(4/Pi) + ((1 + (k - Zeta[3])^(-1))^(k - Zeta[3]))^(4/
        Pi)]}]
}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
ImageSize -> 400](*,Plot[(((1+1/(k-Zeta[3]))^(k-Zeta[3]))/E)^(2/
Pi)x,{x,-1,1}]*)], {{k, E}, 1.3, 30, 0.01}]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. I guess heuristically it explains why we get so close to $\sqrt{2} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when adding up the co-ordinates for the $k = 2$ case.

Comment: (I'll award the bounty when it becomes possible to do so.)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question...?

Comment: I'm satisfied that $x_\infty$ is not a remarkable number with a simple closed form. Of course I'd welcome more information on its properties, and maybe the previous sentence is actually in error (despite my checks at the OEIS), but I think viewing things from the perspective of $1/k$ suggests it's just "some number" in a certain sequence converging to $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Joshua Ciappara Glad you like it. Feel free to change accept though if you get a better answer :) It is an interesting problem! Expanding the terms doesn't look hopeful for a closed solution - but you never know ...